# iphone sdk how to take a picture from camera and show the image in same view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I will create  a button and imageview .I will create IBAction for button to open UIImagepicker to take the photo.I need after that The image need to show in the imageview.How to get this.Can any one help me please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController, UIImage, Memory and More?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this `IBAction` method on a button click.  It will open `UIImagePickerController` to capture an image from the camera.

```
-(IBAction)openCamera
{
    @try 
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
        picker.delegate = self; 

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Camera" message:@"Camera is not available  " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

This delegate will be called when you are finished taking the image. Store that image in your `UIImageView`.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.imageView.image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Comment: 6 seconds :-) and showing in landscape in imageview when i take photo in portrait mode...sorry but this is my last question..

Comment: Its ok to ask questions.. 6 seconds are little more.. What you want with landscape? I do not get it

Comment: When i take the photo in portrait mode.The image is not showing in the  portrait mode.it is turned 90 degrees and showing in landscape mode...

Answer (score 1):

You can declare UIImagePickerDelegate in a header file (.h),
and then on button click event write this below code.

```
-(IBAction)YourMethodName_Clicked:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
                [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) 
                                         inView:self.view
                       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                       animated:YES];

//                [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            }
            else{
                UIAlertView *altnot=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Not Available" message:@"Camera Not Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                altnot.tag=103;
                [altnot show];
                [altnot release];

            }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImageView *imgview1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]];


    imgmain1.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);//set your frame here
    [self.view addSubview:imgmain1];
    [imgmain1 relese];

}
```